# RMAN backup script failing

Tags: oracle, rman

I have a few linux machines and each of them have a few Oracle databases. On each machine we have 2 shell scripts to run the backups. The TSM scheduler calls a script which calls a different backup script for each DB on the machine.

The problem is if I create an array of SIDs and create a loop through the SIDs the backup fails.

```
#!/bin/bash

LEVEL="$1"

declare -a SIDS=('SID1' 'SID2' 'SID3')
su - oracle

for SID in ${SIDS[@]}
do
  ORACLE_SID=$SID; export ORACLE_SID
  export ORACLE_HOME='/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.2'
  ORAENV_ASK=NO
  . /usr/local/bin/oraenv
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  /usr/local/adm/backup-incrn.sh $LEVEL $SID 35
done
```

There is no error in the Logs on the TSM server and it is almost as if the scripts is never called. The logs that are on the machine are not updated with any error messages.

If I use this syntax the backups work perfectly

```
su - oracle -c "/usr/local/adm/backup-incrn.sh $LEVEL SID1 35"

su - oracle -c "/usr/local/adm/backup-incrn.sh $LEVEL SID2 35"
```

I think this has to be an error in my script, some variable not being set properly.

Can anyone see the obvious mistake I've made and point it out to me?

Gísli

Comment: I would like to know why this was migrated. The problem was that the shell script was not correct, although the shell script was used for database administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"su - oracle" is the culprit
```

Remove that line from the script. You can switch the user before you actually run the script.
if you switch user in shell script, then it gives you new shell environment loosing further shell instructions. (there are other ways to do it)

Comment: I have to set the user to oracle in the script. I don't have control over anything else than the script.

Comment: then you need to do: "su - oracle -c '<all your shell statements>'"

Comment: I think this does the trick. Once I have confirmed that the backups run I will mark this as the answer and post the modified script.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that because you're issuing a login your declaration of SIDS is not transferred to the shell started by the su command.  You can test this by checking the value of SIDS after you issue the "su - oracle"

Comment: So if I move the su - oracle to the top, the script would work?

Comment: I think it should work. Try it and see. You don't even need to actually run the backup stuff to examine the environment variables.